# Firebase switch button

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i'm trying to make a realtime button using Javascript and Firebase. Currently I have a working button which is changing the variable in the realtime database from on to off. But the default value isn't saved so when I switch the button off and reload the page it shows that it is on how can I fix this? I also want it to be updated realtime between all the clients

App.js

```
(function() {    
    //Get elements
    const preObject = document.getElementById('object');

    // Create reference
    dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('button').child('value')

    // Sync changes
    dbRefObject.on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));

}());
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log("test");
   });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
    const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('button')

    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
      if (checkbox.checked) {
        dbRefObject.set({value: true})
        console.log('Checked');
      } else {
        dbRefObject.set({value: false})
        console.log('Not checked');
      }
    });
  });
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"></script>

    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked>
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </label>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the data from the database, but not doing anything useful with it yet here:

```
dbRefObject.on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));}
```

To have the button reflect the state that you store in the database, use this listener to update the button's state:

```
dbRefObject.on('value', (snap) {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
  checkbox.checked = snap.val().value;
})
```